# SonataAdmin - form collections

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm trying to embed a `Product Variant` into my `Product` admin using `SonataAdminBundle`.

So `one` Product has `many` Variants

I have the following Entities:

`Product.php`

```
/**
 * @var ProductVariant $variants
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="ProductVariant", cascade={"persist", "remove"} )
 **/
protected $variants;
```

`ProductVariant.php`

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="variants")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $product;
```

Now, I have the following in my Admin Form class:

```
        ->add('variants','collection', array(
           'type' =>  new ProductVariantType(),
           'allow_add' => true,
       ), array(
           'edit' => 'inline',
           'inline' => 'table',
       ))
```

This displays the Add Button to add a new Variant, but after clicking on it, I'd expect the row to be `inline` and within a `table`, but these options don't seem to get triggered.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Only `sonata_type_collection` supports options `'edit'` and `'inline'`. Not core `collection` type.